# Edit Text Paste option is not showing in overlay Window Service

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-service

I have a overlay windows service . but when I hold touch on `EditText` in it, copy, paste options not showing at all.
my xml file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/service_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/service_icon"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/star_filled" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/expanded_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/service_searchBox"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:hint="@string/searchboxHint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="textPhonetic"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textColorHint="#a5a5a5"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/close_service_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/service_elevation"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/service_close"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and java class:

```
public class MyWindowServices extends Service {

  private WindowManager              mWindowManager;
  private WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowsParams;
  private View                       mView;
  private boolean wasInFocus = true;

  private int height;

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_service_layout, null);

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    moveView();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  private void moveView() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    height = metrics.heightPixels;

    mWindowsParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 25) ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
      ,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
      PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


    mWindowsParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    mWindowsParams.y = height / 9;
    mWindowsParams.x = 0;
    //TODO runtime permission is needed
    mWindowManager.addView(mView, mWindowsParams);

    mView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      private int initialX;
      private int initialY;
      private float initialTouchX;
      private float initialTouchY;

      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <= 300) {
          return false;
        }
        if (isViewInBounds(mView, (int) (event.getRawX()), (int) (event.getRawY()))) {
          editTextReceiveFocus();
        } else {
          editTextDontReceiveFocus();
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialX = mWindowsParams.x;
            initialY = mWindowsParams.y;
            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mWindowsParams.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
            mWindowsParams.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
            mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mView, mWindowsParams);
            break;
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  private boolean isViewInBounds(View view, int x, int y) {
    Rect  outRect  = new Rect();
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getDrawingRect(outRect);
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);
    return outRect.contains(x, y);
  }

  private void editTextReceiveFocus() {
    if (!wasInFocus) {
      mWindowsParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;
      mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mView, mWindowsParams);
      wasInFocus = true;
    }
  }

  private void editTextDontReceiveFocus() {
    if (wasInFocus) {
      mWindowsParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;
      mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mView, mWindowsParams);
      wasInFocus = false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {

    if (mView != null) {
      mWindowManager.removeView(mView);
    }

    super.onDestroy();
  }

}
```

[image]

I want when user long click on EditText, show copy and paste option above it.

UPDATE:
same layout show paste option in normal activity but not showing in overlay service.
maybe my problem is here:

```
mWindowsParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 25) ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
          ,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
          PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: Hi, I just encountered this issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Hi @QasimMalik, sorry for the late answer. I don't remember what I did. But I think I showed a custom menu on LongClick pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will definitely consider this approach.